# C# Json and HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, json, steam

I used `HttpWebRequest` to get the content from a website.
The problem is that I got a response in json and I don't really know how to use, convert and implement that data in my program.

Current code:

```
namespace Web_Scraper
{
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=440&market_hash_name=Genuine%20Purity%20Fist");
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


                StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());


                string final_response = stream.ReadToEnd();



                Console.WriteLine("Genuine Purity Fist");
                Console.WriteLine(final_response);
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"1,05\u20ac","volume":"26","median_price":"1,06\u20ac"}
```

json2csharp code:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string lowest_price { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
    public string median_price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you could downloade Json.NET and parse your json string like this:

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=440&market_hash_name=Genuine%20Purity%20Fist");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());


            var final_response = stream.ReadToEnd();

            // Converts the unicode to string correctValue.


            string correctValue = "Euro";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(final_response);
            if (sb.ToString().Contains("\\u20ac"))
            {                
                sb.Replace("\\u20ac", correctValue);
            }            

            dynamic items = JObject.Parse(sb.ToString());

            bool success = items.success;
            string lowest = items.lowest_price;
            string volume = items.volume;
            string median = items.median_price;            

            // Create a test object of RootObject class and display it's values in cw.
            RootObject r = new RootObject(success, lowest, volume, median);
            Console.WriteLine("TEST OBJECT VALUES: Success: " + r.success + ", lPrice: " + r.lowest_price + ", vol: " + r.volume + ", mPrice: " + r.median_price + "\n");

            // Calculation example
            double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(r.FixComma(r.lowest_price,correctValue));
            double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(r.FixComma(r.median_price, correctValue));
            double result = num1 + num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result+"\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Genuine Purity Fist");
            Console.WriteLine(final_response);
            Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public string lowest_price { get; set; }
        public string volume { get; set; }
        public string median_price { get; set; }

        public RootObject(bool success, string lowest_price, string volume, string median_price)
        {
            this.success = success;
            this.lowest_price = lowest_price;
            this.volume = volume;
            this.median_price = median_price;
        }

        public string FixComma(string value,string currency)
        {
            string correctValue = ".";
            string correctValue2 = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value);
            if (sb.ToString().Contains(","))
            {
                sb.Replace(",", correctValue);
            }
            if (sb.ToString().Contains(currency))
            {
                sb.Replace(currency, correctValue2);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a link that explains how to downloade Json.NET https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/.

Comment: Got two errors at the two RootObject, would also like a bit of explanation to the code, if possible.

Comment: Did u add a constructor down in your RootObject class?

Comment: Added constructor down in rootobject class, and made a test in Main where I've created a RootObject and then printed it out.

Comment: I just copied your code, I've done nothing else with it and I get the "The type or namespace name 'RootObject'..."

Comment: Hey try copy it now I edited it so it shows the entire code and not just part of it.

Comment: Just remember to change the namespace "Consoleapplication1" to "Web_Scraper".

Comment: I fixed it I think by removing the `Console.WriteLine("Success: "+r...` and changing `Console.WriteLine(final_response);` to `Console.WriteLine(lowest)`. The only problem now is that I get a questionmark after the price (1,04?)

Comment: Hey apperently the console application does not support the € sign and therefor isn't able to display it correctly, I'm not sure how to fix it, but I re-edited the code again and added a method that should replce the ? with $. You can just replace the $ in string correctValue with "Euro".

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help! One last question, the strings (lowest, median and volume), is there any way I can use those in calculations?

Comment: Yes you can make calculations but you need to replace the comma in the number with a dot in the string lowerst/median. I updated the code again with an example of how you could add lowest and median, output: http://imgur.com/0YER6UC

Comment: Didn't quite work, but I'll try to fix it tomorrow. Did you add/change anything else except the FixComma at the bottom and the calculation example?

Comment: No didn't change anything else, what errors do you get?

Comment: Well, there's no errors in the code. But I get this msg when I try to run it: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format." It shows up at the "double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(r.FixComma(r.lowest_price, correctValue));"

Comment: Try repaste the whole thing in again, should not bring up that error. The error you're getting is either because the comma doesn't get replaced with a dot or correctValue not being replaced with an empty string "".

Comment: Still the same problem at the same place.

Comment: Try add this using statement: "using System.Globalization;", and replace Convert.ToDouble(r.FixComma(r.lowest_price,correctValue)); and the one with median price with double.Parse(r.FixComma(r.lowest_price,correctValue),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Worked perfectly now! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class in the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace.

For example:

```
RootObject obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(final_response);
```

Other options might be:

- Do it yourself using reflection or manual parsing.
- Third-party libraries like [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll see what I can do with this.

Comment: Well, don't really understand what I am supposed to do. Where should I put this code? I also get an errors with the JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: Put this code under `string final_response` - and what errors are you getting with `JavaScriptSerializer`?

Comment: Well, when I got the least errors, I had an error with it, can't remember what it was though. Btw, am I supposed to make a new class with the json2csharp code or just put it in there above your code? I've seen multiple variants on google and I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: Yes. add the code you were given by `json2csharp` then you can create the required objects.

Comment: Ok, now the error is back "The type or namespace name 'JavaScriptSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: You are missing to add the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for this. It provides a powerful and flexible way to deserialize and consume the data (and lets you change your mind about how to do it fairly easily later). It's also available [as a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).

The simplest way would be to deserialize it into a `dynamic` or `Object` instance:

```
var object = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Object>(final_response);
var isSuccessful = object.success; // true or false
// ...
```

(You can replace `object` with `dynamic` too.)

If you want to deserialize to a class, create one:

```
class PriceData {
  public bool success { get; set; }
  public string lowest_price { get; set; }
  public string  volume { get; set; }
  public string median_price { get; set; }
}
```

Then call `.Deserialize<PriceData>(final_response)` instead.

If you don't like lowercase-named or underscore-named variables (which is not the common style in C#), you can override the deserialization to specify which field to use for which C# property:

```
class PriceData {
  [JsonProperty("success")]
  public bool Success { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("lowest_price")]
  public string LowestPrice { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("volume")]
  public string  Volume { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("median_price")]
  public string MedianPrice { get; set; }
}
```